# Disable zip downloads from github

Tags: github

Is there any way to **disable** viewers to download my files from github?
I want to show my work, but I am afraid anybody can steal my code.

Comment: That makes no sense. There are other ways to download the code ( `git clone`) not only by downloading the ZIP file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent the cloning of my github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573950/how-can-i-prevent-the-cloning-of-my-github-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, Github actually means you want to share something with the community, or you are showcasing your work in the open source community. Unfortunately you cannot restrict the users from downloading your content from your Repository.

Alternatively what you can do Just make your Repository private. But then in this case you are not able to make you work available to view for audience.

More you can read here :-
https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/limiting-interactions-in-your-repository

Answer (score 0):

Disabling zip/tarballs on GitHub at the moment seems to be impossible, but it would be useful for those using git submodules, which are not included in the automatic created archives, where the repository owner could replace them with a continuous integration job with something like [git-archive-all](https://github.com/Kentzo/git-archive-all).